# Error creating Azure Managed Cache

Tags: powershell, caching, azure

I am trying to create a managed cache in Azure and according to the instructions I need to invoke the following command (or its ilk) in Azure Powershell:

```
New-AzureManagedCache -Name contosocache -Location "South Central US" -Sku Basic -Memory 128MB
```

I am logged in using Add-AzureAccount but get the following error:

> "The term New-AzureManagedCache is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet"

When I interrogate the help (Help Azure) there is no mention of any commands for Managed Cache. I know the Redis cache is set to supplant the Managed Cache but Redis is not available in SE Asia yet so I have no choice but managed cache, yet it seems to have been removed ?

Does anybody know if there is something I am missing here or if it is a general error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you download the latest version of the Azure PowerShell module from here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/releases. As of right now, the latest version is 0.8.4, released on June 30th.

Then, to ensure that the `New-AzureManagedCache` command is available in your PowerShell session, run:

```
Get-Command -Module Azure -Name *cache*;
```

Comment: Thank you. I just assumed that the version of Azure Powershell I downloaded a couple of months ago would have had the ManagedCache commands.. That will teach me to assume :)

Comment: Mark: Glad you got things sorted out. I agree, assumptions are generally not a good idea. Trust, but verify! :)